# t-sql - store procedure - input date and date comparison with smalldatetime field

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, datetime

I have to write a stored with an input date:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[csoft_SAT_Festivita_Delete]
(
myData SMALLDATETIME
)
AS
BEGIN
```

...

In the stored I have to do some comparisons like this

```
SELECT
...
WHERE
myDataFiels = @myData
```

To find all the records in a given year/month/day.

But if I don't do some conversions the result is not the one I expect.

- What is the best way to input the date parameter?
- What is the best way to do the comparison?

In the web there are many suggestions an I'm a little confused....
In the table the field is a smalldatetime.
Pileggi

Comment: what is the type of your column `myDataFiels` ?

Comment: I have edited the post: smalldatetime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is the datatype of the table fields in your comparison? Generally, it's best to compare with similar datatypes.

In most cases, it is recommended to use the `DATETIME` datatype, as `SMALLDATETIME` is not ANSI or ISO 8601 compliant.

Also, could you elaborate a bit on what you are trying to achieve with your comparison? For example, if you want to filter all records that occur on a given day, you should do something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[csoft_SAT_Festivita_Delete]
(
    @myDTparam DATETIME
)
AS
BEGIN  

...

SELECT
...
WHERE
    myDTfield >= CAST(@myDTparam AS DATE) AND 
    myDTfield < CAST(@myDTparam + 1 AS DATE)
```

This is possible when using the `DATETIME` datatype, because this datatype supports integer addition/subtraction in order to add or subtract days. Also, when you cast a `DATETIME` to a `DATE`, you strip the time portion of the `DATETIME` value, but it is still possible to compare a `DATE` value to a `DATETIME` value.

Comment: Okay, but what kind of comparison do you need to perform? Do you want to find all records within a given day/month/year/hour? The answer depends a lot on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: yes - sorry - I need to find all records within a given day/month/year.

Comment: I suggest your update your question with that. You can still use `SMALLDATETIME`, but in order to find all records on a given day, you should cast both your field and your parameter: `WHERE CAST(myDataFiels AS DATE) = CAST(@myData AS DATE)`. To find all records in a given year, simply do: `WHERE YEAR(myDataFiels) = YEAR(@myData)`. To do the same for months: `WHERE YEAR(myDataFiels) = YEAR(@myData) AND MONTH(myDataFiels) = MONTH(@myData)`

Comment: thank you very very much! for storing the holiday days, do you think that datetime is better than smalldatetime?

Comment: The best thing to do, is to be consistent throughout your database. So if your database already uses smalldatetime, you should keep using it when creating new columns. The only difference between smalldatetime and datetime, is that smalldatetime is only accurate down to one minute, where as datetime is accurate down to 1/300 of a second. For storing holiday days, it doesn't matter which one you choose.